# CSS a div at bottom and width:auto but width:auto failed

Tags: html, css

```
<style>
.alt{
    width:auto;
    height:50px;
        text-align
    background:#333;
    border-top:2px solid #000; 
    box-shadow:0 0 10px #000;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
}
</style>

<div class="alt">
TEXT CONTENT    
</div>
```

width:auto is not working correct i dont know why. it should be wide same as browser screen but it just wide as half of screen

Comment: What is not working exactly? Give us some more code or an example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Define "not working correctly".  What is it doing and what is it you expect it to do that it is not?

Comment: try `0 auto` to see if it "works" (@MatthewRapati Sorry you are right. I was thinking of something else)

Comment: @SiKni8 that isn't valid

Comment: The `div` is not expanding its `width` to fit its surroundings because it has `position: absolute;` applied to it. You can apply `width: 100%;` instead to get it to be the same `width` as its container.

Comment: xD my mistake true auto is not fit 100% solved my problem thank you SombreErmine-San